# Degrees, Minutes and seconds regex

Tags: regex

I need validate with RegEx an sexagecimal value, for example: 24° 12' 55,4" or 32° 24' 15,4".

For now, I have the next RegEx, that matches successful with degrees and minutes:

```
^([0-8][0-9]|[9][0])°\s([0-4][0-9]|[5][9])'$
```

But, when add the seconds validator have problems:

```
^([0-8][0-9]|[9][0])°\s([0-4][0-9]|[5][9])'\s([0-4][0-9]|[5][9],[0-9])''$
```

I'm new with RegEx, any ideas?

Comment: Could you specify "problems" with concrete values that are wrongly accepted or rejected? Surely you can simply copy them out of your tests? ;)

Comment: `^([0-8][0-9]|[9][0])°\s([0-4][0-9]|[5][9])'\s((?:[0-4][0-9]|[5][9]),[0-9])''$`  Maybe.  But I don't know your engine.  Which language are you using?

Comment: Are you sure `"` is the same as `''`?

Comment: Doing this kind of value validation with a regex just gives you a more complicated regex and more confusing error messages. I would strongly recommend you just use \d+ for the numeric parts, and deal with them being out of range in code. For example, do you really want to not allow values 50 through 58 for minutes and seconds (you're allowing 00-49 then 59), or did you just copy blindly from the way the degrees are validated for 00-89 or 90?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, you have some redundancy:

```
^([0-8][0-9]|[9][0])°\s([0-4][0-9]|[5][9])'$
```

can become just:

```
^([0-8][0-9]|90)°\s([0-4][0-9]|59)'$
```

Next you have a logical issue, in your second match, you're matching 0-4 then 0-9 (ie 00-49) and then matching just 59.  You can change this to:

```
^([0-8][0-9]|90)°\s[0-5][0-9]'$
```

to match 00-59

Next let's look at your seconds modification:

```
\s([0-4][0-9]|[5][9],[0-9])''$
```

Same issue as before, except now you've added a decimal, but not to both sides of the | so it will only match on one side, if we fix this like we fixed the last one we get:

```
^([0-8][0-9]|90)°\s[0-5][0-9]'\s[0-5][0-9],[0-9]''$
```

Next you have two single quotes instead of a double quote, so fix that:

```
^([0-8][0-9]|90)°\s([0-5][0-9])'\s[0-5][0-9],[0-9]"$
```

Now we need to ask ourselves, is the first digit on this mandatory?  Probably not.  So mark it as potentially missing using a `?`

```
^([0-8]?[0-9]|90)°\s[0-5]?[0-9]'\s[0-5]?[0-9],[0-9]"$
```

Next, is the fractional part of the second mandatory?  Probably not, so mark it as potentially missing:

```
^([0-8]?[0-9]|90)°\s[0-5]?[0-9]'\s[0-5]?[0-9](,[0-9])?"$
```

Finally, I'm assuming that each part except for the degrees is not required, mark them as potentially missing:

```
^([0-8]?[0-9]|90)°(\s[0-5]?[0-9]')?(\s[0-5]?[0-9](,[0-9])?")?$
```

There's other things you can do to make this better.  But, this should get you started.

Comment: I improved the regex made by @OmnipotentEntity: `/^([0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-3]?[0-6]?[0-9]|360)?°?\s?([0-5]?[0-9])?'?\s?([0-5]?[0-9](,[0-9])?)?"?$/mg` Here you are an example test: 359° 59' 0" // Match | 125° 59' 59" // Match | 0° 0' 0" // Match | 90° 0' 0" // Match | 2° 1' 3" // Match | 390° // No match | 1000° 1' 2" // No match | 360° 0' 0" // Match | 361° 61' 61" // No match | 180° 0' // Match | 180° // Match. You can find the regex at https://regex101.com/r/IAxQ7X/1

Comment: Good Job with extending the regular expression!  Unfortunately, both your implementation and mine seem to erroneously match angles between 360° and 361°.  For instance, 360° 1' 0" is a match. (90° and 91° in my implementation.)  You can work around this problem by doing 90° (or 360°) separately: `^(([0-8]?[0-9])°(\s[0-5]?[0-9]')?(\s[0-5]?[0-9](,[0-9])?")?|90°(\s0')?(\s(0(,0*)?")?`

Answer (score 2):

I've recently had a similar use case but had to match variations such as

```
14° 58' 40.068" E
36°57'9" N
```

so I came up with

```
(\d+)\s?\°\s?(\d+)\s?\'\s?(\d{1,}\.?\,?\d{0,}?)\"\s?(N|W|S|E)
```

Testable [here](https://regex101.com/r/MzJeQI/4/).

Comment: This is matching [123456°123456'123.,456"N](https://regex101.com/r/MzJeQI/5)

Comment: Thanks. Though it's specifically designed to match relevant subsequent groups like so https://prnt.sc/spmol6, plus there are actual geo validators down the line. Know of any way to keep the groups as they are but enforce the DMS standard?

Answer (score 1):

I needed a far more robust solution for an open-source project, [qalGeohash-TSQL](https://github.com/qalocate/qalgeohash-tsql), than has been provided in both the answers and comments on this question.

After two hours of playing with solutions within [this fantastic online Regex exploration resource](https://regexr.com/), I finally have exactly what I needed; a precisely limited domain for each of both longitude (x-axis) and latitude (y-axis).

### Longitude Solution:

- URL At Which to Explore/Experiment (includes test cases): https://regexr.com/5lcpk
- RegEx: `^((180[°|\s]\s*)(0{1,2}['|\s]\s*)(0{1,2}([.|,]0{1,20})?["|\s]\s*)|((1[0-7]\d|\d\d|\d)[°|\s]\s*)(([0-5]\d|\d)['|\s]\s*)(([0-5]\d|\d)([.|,]\d{1,20})?["|\s]\s*))[EWew]$`

### Latitude Solution:

- URL At Which to Explore/Experiment (includes test cases): https://regexr.com/5lcq9
- RegEx: `^((90[°|\s]\s*)(0{1,2}['|\s]\s*)(0{1,2}([.|,]0{1,20})?["|\s]\s*)|(([1-8]\d|\d)[°|\s]\s*)(([0-5]\d|\d)['|\s]\s*)(([0-5]\d|\d)([.|,]\d{1,20})?["|\s]\s*))[NSns]$`

---

Below is a breakdown of the components which compose the above solutions:

### Longitude Components:

- At 180:

  - Degrees: `(180[°|\s]\s*)`
  - Minutes: `(0{1,2}['|\s]\s*)`
  - Seconds: `(0{1,2}([.|,]0{1,20})?["|\s]\s*)`
- Below 180:

  - Degrees: `((1[0-7]\d|\d\d|\d)[°|\s]\s*)`
  - Minutes: `(([0-5]\d|\d)['|\s]\s*)`
  - Seconds: `(([0-5]\d|\d)([.|,]\d{1,20})?["|\s]\s*)`
- Directional: `[EWew]`

### Latitude Components:

- At 90:

  - Degrees: `(90[°|\s]\s*)`
  - Minutes: `(0{1,2}['|\s]\s*)`
  - Seconds: `(0{1,2}([.|,]0{1,20})?["|\s]\s*)`
- Below 90:

  - Degrees: `(([1-8]\d|\d)[°|\s]\s*)`
  - Minutes: `(([0-5]\d|\d)['|\s]\s*)`
  - Seconds: `(([0-5]\d|\d)([.|,]\d{1,20})?["|\s]\s*)`
- Directional: `[NSns]`

Comment: This might be the only solution that takes into account culture codes besides en-US.

Answer (score 1):

This is an improvement of @OmnipotentEntity regex.

**Features**:

- Negative angle match
- Stop match at (+/-)360° (so it doesn't match something like `360° 7' 24"`, but only `360°`)
- Match separately degrees (max `360°`), minutes (max `59`) and seconds (max 59.9")
- Match integer for degrees, and minutes, but float (1 digit precision) for seconds

Be aware that it accepts only point decimal separator (`.`) for seconds. Change this depending on your needs.

**Angle degrees, minutes and seconds regex**:

```regex
/^(?:(-?360(*ACCEPT))|(-?[1-3]?[0-9]?[0-9]?))°?\s?([0-5]?[0-9])?\'?\s?([0-5]?[0-9](?:.{1}[0-9])?)?"?$/
```

That's a link to a [regex playground](https://regex101.com/r/z0N7GP/1) to try what's the limit of this expression.