# Angles degrees, minutes and second regular expression

Tags: regex, trigonometry, angle

Having the need to find a regex to match angles degrees, minutes and seconds (*not geoposition format*) in in order to build an Angle PHP object , I found only [this stackoverflow answer by @OmnipotentEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321779/degrees-minutes-and-seconds-regex#18321900). Inspired by this, I improved the above regex.

Answer (score 0):

**Features**:

- Negative angle match
- Stop match at (+/-)360°
- Match separately degrees (max 360°), minutes (max 59) and seconds (max 59.9'/")
- Match integer for degrees, and minutes, but float (1 digit precision) for seconds

**Angle degrees, minutes and seconds regex**:
`/^(-?360(*ACCEPT))|(-?[1-3]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)°?\s?([0-5]?[0-9])?\'?\s?([0-5]?[0-9].?[0-9]?)?\"$/mg`

That's a link to a [regex playground](https://regex101.com/r/bIliHs/1) with matching and non-matching examples.