# Regex for latitude and longitude with form DDMMSSX

Tags: regex

Which is the regex expression for latitude and longitude expressed as DDMMSS, where D is for degrees, M is for minutes, S is for seconds and X is a letter to indicate North (N), South, East or West?

For example, for a latitude 60 degrees, 20 minutes, 15 seconds North, it would be **602015N**,
and for a longitude 40 degrees, 50 minutes, 0 seconds West, it would be **0405000W**. (Please note that latitude always has 6 digits, and longitude always has 7 digits).

Also, taking in mind that minutes and seconds must be between 00 and 59, and degrees must be between 0 and 90 (for latitude) and between 0 and 180 (for longitude).

Comment: I am using JAVA to check if a given String matches the pattern. I know how to do that, but I don't know how to design a regex code. It's like ancient runes for me

Comment: I don't understand, so you have a working regular expression ! What else do you need ?

Comment: I just came up with a solution for my particular use cases. It does not appear to handle your specific case. However, given how I approached it, you might find it a useful place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321779/degrees-minutes-and-seconds-regex/65974086#65974086

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these two regular expressions:

**latitude**

```
(?:[0-8]\d|90)(?:[0-5]\d)(?:[0-5]\d)[NS]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/adL2W_UAp8iSa4N3)

---

**longitude**

```
(?:0\d{2}|1[0-7]\d|180)(?:[0-5]\d)(?:[0-5]\d)[EW]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/i4MSCTC4N5AHN2iM)

**Nota:**
Don't forget to escape `\` in your java code, you can use the ignore case flag if letters  (NSEW) can be in lower case.

```
 String latitude=...
 final String LATITUDE_REGEX = "(?:[0-8]\\d|90)(?:[0-5]\\d)(?:[0-5]\\d)[NS]";
 // the same regex with ignore case flag activated
 // final String LATITUDE_REGEX = "(?i)(?:[0-8]\\d|90)(?:[0-5]\\d)(?:[0-5]\\d)[NS]"; 

 if (latitude.matches(LATITUDE_REGEX)) {
     // We have a latitude ...
 } else {
     // This is not a latitude...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

The following Stackoverflow QA should help you...

[Degrees Minutes Seconds (DMS) RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611668/degrees-minutes-seconds-dms-regex)

```
^\s*([+-]?\d{1,3}\*?\s+\d{1,2}'?\s+\d{1,2}"?[NSEW]?|\d{1,3}(:\d{2}){2}\.\d[NSEW]\s*){1,2}$
```

Comment: That pattern matches coordinates given as signed float numbers. It is not what I am asking for

Comment: Updated the link and Regex

Answer (score 0):

In this code not comtemplates Ex. 1800000N. You need add this code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEO3f.png)

```
lat:  ((900000)|([0-8]\d([0-5]\d)([0-5]\d)))[NS]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEC2C.png)

```
long: ((1800000)|(?:0\d{2}|1[0-7]\d|1800000)(?:[0-5]\d)(?:[0-5]\d))[EW]
```